# Enabling / Disabling tasks in Task Scheduler using a Powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to disable a task in the Windows task scheduler using PowerShell.
How can I do this?

```
$tasks = & SCHTASKS /Query /V /FO CSV | ConvertFrom-Csv
$task = $tasks | ? { $_.TaskName -eq "E:\MyDir\test.bat" }  
& SCHTASKS /Change /DISABLE /TN "$Task.TaskName"
```

This error is the result:

> ERROR: The specified task name ".TaskName" does not exist in the system.

Answer (score 3):

"$($task.Taskname)" should work.

Comment: thanks!! that worked. But it's asking me for my windows user password for disabling. Is there a way we can disable a task without the script asking for the password?

Comment: Run the script with an elevated console?

Comment: could you please elobarate as to what "elevated console" means?

Comment: "Run as Administrator" is what @SpellingD meant.